# Apache error log shows :-unable to load php_pspell.dll

Tags: php, zend-framework

I m getting a whitescreen on browsing the public folder of a zend application code.On checking the apache error log file i found the following errorvlog:Apache error log shows :-unable to load php_pspell.dll.

Comment: take a look at the syntax highlighting of this post. get yourself a proper IDE or at least something that does syntax highlighting.

Comment: check your code you have marked ‘ instead of ' in first line then check error still there.

Comment: The opening quote in your `require_once` statement is incorrect. Syntax errors are deemed off-topic on this site, BTW, so this question will be closed. PS: use an editor with syntax highlighting, and use `php -l path/to/file.php` when in doubt (lint-check your code). The reason why PHP mentions line 21 is simply because all of the `;` (statement ending chars) are treated as strings, because of the quotes mismatch

Comment: now i am getting a white screen.any possible reasons?

Comment: Apache error log shows :-unable to load php_pspell.dll.Shall I copy it to php/ext/.It is not present right now

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
require_once ‘Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
```

**error this line for `‘` to `'`**

```
 require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';


    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
    // Load configuration
    Zend_Registry::set('configSection', $configSection);
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(ROOT_DIR.'/application/configuration/config.ini', $configSection);
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
```

Comment: Whats the change here

Comment: @tks: Check the syntax highlighting! Unless you're on a monochrome display, you aught to see that `$autoloader = ...` is no longer ***red***, because the opening and closing quotes of the first statement _match_

Answer (score 1):

use proper quoting  try to replace `‘` to `'`(single quote)

```
require_once ‘Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
```

to

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
```

Comment: any reason for the white screen i m getting now?

Comment: echo some data on that page

Comment: then all ok check your code is for some output? else will be blank page